# SQL Group By Multiple values on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
Section    TestID        Score

Section1   1             50
Section2   1             32
Section3   1             22
Section1   2             22
Section2   2             17 
Section3   2             42
```

I'm looking to produce a table with each section and it's scores against all testIDs (up to a maximum of 3 scores). Is it possible to use a group by condition to produce a table similar to this:

```
Section    Score1     Score2

Section1   50          22
Section2   32          17
Section3   22          42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.section,
  max(case when t.rn = 1 then t.score end) score1,
  max(case when t.rn = 2 then t.score end) score2
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by section order by testid) rn
  from tablename
) t
group by t.section
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=336d7b140fb2a3d2b552b4863e4cc2f4).
Results:

```
> section  | score1 | score2
> :------- | -----: | -----:
> Section1 |     50 |     22
> Section2 |     32 |     17
> Section3 |     22 |     42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select section,
       max(case when testid = 1 then score end) as score_1,
       max(case when testid = 2 then score end) as score_2
from t
group by section;
```